# Calculating euclidean distance in a matrix

Tags: c, euclidean-distance, code-translation, euclidean-algorithm

I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance in a matrix in C, I saw a similar post and tried it on my own matrix but as it is different I do not know how to make it work. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    double distance[3][3] = {0};
    double myArray[3][9] = {{50, 10, 10, 20, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                            {50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 10, 15, 5},
                            {70, 10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0}};

    int i;
    int j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            double temp = 0.0f;

            for (k = 0; k < 9; k++)
            {
                temp += pow(myArray[i][k] - myArray[j][k], 2);
            }
            distance[i][j] = (int)sqrt(temp);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {

            printf("%f ", distance[i][j]);
            if (j == 2)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is close to being correct, but it displays like this:

```
0.000000 38.000000 28.000000 
38.000000 0.000000 35.000000 
28.000000 35.000000 0.000000 
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `double distance[3][3] ... for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) .. distance[i][j]` You are overflowing the `distance` array. It's only 3x3 but you are writing to a 3x9.

Comment: What exactly is the `distance` array supposed to represent?

Comment: The distance `distance` array is for displaying the resulted distance between a ->a, a-> b, a -> c, b ->a, b->b, b ->c and c->a, c -> b, c->c @user3386109

Comment: Oh, so those are intended to be 9-dimensional points? In that case, the loops should be `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)` just like the loops where you're printing the `distance` array.

Comment: Why are you casting the `sqrt` to an `int`, when the `distance` array is an array of `double`?

Comment: I just edited the question because i notice my previous mistake of the first `for`,  It nows displays what i want but still i am getting the error of `*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated`

Comment: It's still accessing out of bounds: `double distance[3][3]; double myArray[3][9];`, but then `myArray[j][k]` and `distance[i][j]`, where `j` can go up to `j < 9`.

Comment: You fixed the first `for` loop by changing the 2 to a 3. Now you need to fix the second `for` loop by changing the 9 to a 3.